# Reset Pentaho biserver 6.1 admin password

Tags: admin, pentaho, change-password, forgot-password

I changed admin password, and today when I tried to login I got error message.

I have to reset it, but all pages I find tell me it is in [administration-console\resource\config\login.properties](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?70238-Changing-Admin-console-password). Looks like login file had changed, because my server doesn't have a `administration-console` folder. Still, I pages I find are outdated and point to this same file. I'm using biserver-ce-6.1.0.1-196.

Where is admin password stored now and how to reset it?

Comment: Are you using the community or the enterprise edition?